# Solve given equation to a approximate value

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

Can some explain to me how the relation shown below gives $\log k$ on approximation?

$$x = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{1 }{k-i}$$

Comment: letting $j=k-i$ gives $\sum \limits_{j=1}^k \frac1j$ as an expression for the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$x = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{1 }{k-i}= 1+1/2+1/3+...+1/k$$

Also note that the above sum is an approximation to $$ \int _1 ^k (1/x)dx = \ln k $$

That is reason behind the approximation.